# Glut32 is missing with OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glut

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenGL with C++ with the book OpenGL 5th Edition.
In the first exmaple they include the files GLTools.h and GLShaderManager.h.
I'm trying to extract the book content and compile it, but I'm getting a lot of errors so I tried to include before those files the file glew.h or Windows.h, after I include this file I get only 1 error.
"error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut32.lib'" so I tried to google it and I found that I have to add to Microsoft Sdks library so I did it but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing [a GLUT implementation](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to `Glut32.lib` in project properties.

Comment: How does the OP do that? Can you provide more context?

Comment: I am sorry but what is "OP" ?

Comment: OP = the Original Post or Original Poster

Comment: That will depend on what IDE he is using.